# Grep / Sed results and search term into new file

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have this command

`{cmd with search term of FOOTBALL_CLUB} | grep ^manager >> output file`

eg

`{cmd with search term of MANCHESTER_UTD} | grep ^manager >> output file`

`{cmd with search term of BARCELONA} | grep ^manager >> output file`

Assume that the search term will return all details about the searched FOOTBALL_CLUB and then grep out their manager. It will then write it to a file.

How can I get the search term and the result into the output file? At the moment it is just the result and ideally I want to have the search term and the result in the output file.

Can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was

`echo FOOTBALL_CLUB`{cmd with search term of MANCHESTER_UTD} | grep ^manager >> output file`

and that worked

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function for this:

```
srch() {
   local term="${1?needs term}"
   local out='output.log'
   echo "Search Term: $term" >> "$out"
   cmd_with_search_term "$term" | grep '^manager' >> "$out"
}
```

then use it as:

```
srch FOOTBALL_CLUB
srch BARCELONA
```